# Facebook returns "This webpage contains a blocked URL"

Tags: facebook, debugging, javascript-debugger

I've set up an FB app which needs to post on the user's wall. But FB gives this error "this post contains a blocked URL".

This is the URL to the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.koopwel.nl

I want to use Remarketing apps like "Shoelace" but they are unable to create ad creatives because of: "Can't download: Could not retrieve data from URL."

Also when I'm trying to "Fetch latest information" at the debugger it does not provide any information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Hi CKE, I wish I was able to do so... but literally I have zero experience with coding. Facebook support has sent me over here.. I don't know how to solve the issue, they told me I will find the help I need here.. :(

Comment: Facebook may have misdirected you on the basis they cannot help you with your coding. Readers here can, but on the basis they are volunteers here in their spare time, they won't do it for you. Do you have a web developer or social media marketing person who may be able to assist you at your location/organisation?